# How to Register, login, and get user permissions using WSO2 IS with Spring Boot or java

Tags: java, spring-boot, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I read all the WSO2 IS documentation to understand how to login, register, and get user permissions through the Restful APIs. Finally, I did the login and registration, but I don't know how to get **user permissions**, and this is my point!

Comment: Are you looking for a REST API to retrieve the assigned permissions to a user via roles?

Comment: @AnuradhaKarunarathna, could you please send me doc, or anything related to that?

Comment: Could you please explain your use case a bit? eg: one use case would be once the user login to an application after authenticating by WSO2 IS application wants to be handled based on the user's permissions. 2. Admin user wants to see another user's allowed permissions

Comment: Also, Could you please mention the version of IS that you use

Comment: No, all me need just let user login after that get user permissions by api also to tell the front-end side to check if this user possible to see orders, and create user as example.

As example if i login with normal employee with this permissions (
  can_see_order : true,
 ca_create_user: false
)

Comment: @AnuradhaKarunarathna
Identity provider API 
6.1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are building an oauth/oidc based application, instead of using separate REST APIs, you can use the permission handler https://github.com/nilasini/CustomPermissionClaimHandler to include user's permissions into the ID token.

If you want to get a user's permission through a REST API, there is no one single API to get that. The option is,

1. Get the user's assigned roles by one of the following API based on your usecase

- `https://<host>:<port>/scim2/Users/<user-id>?attributes=roles` (This can be invoked by a privileged user to get another user's assigned roles)
- `https://<host>:<port>/scim2/Me?attributes=roles` (Loggegin user can get his own roles)

2. Then per each assigned role, invoke the following API to get the assigned permissions to the role

- `https://<host>:<port>/scim2/Roles/<role-id>?attributes=permissions`

Here is a reference for the mentioned scim REST APIs: https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/apis/scim2-rest-apis/

Comment: Thank you so much, i have one more question. after i login to using restfull api using the following uri https://localhost:9443/api/identity/auth/v1.1/authenticate . now i have a token, but when i tried to use it to get my permissons any request it's giving Authorization failure. my question is how to use this token?

Comment: and please one more question, how add attributes to the token? or there is a way to add permissions to the token?

Comment: The API localhost:9443/api/identity/auth/v1.1/authenticate can only be used to validate the user credentials. If you want to access the scim2 APIs using a token go for oauth based tokens https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/references/concepts/authorization/access-token/